# Mock android.os.BaseBundle without roboelectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am trying to do a unit test on this code :

```
Bundle cidParam(String accountId) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle(1);
    params.putString(Params.CID, accountId);

    return params;
}
```

This is the unit test :

```
private void mockBundle(String cid) throws Exception {
    Bundle mBundle = PowerMockito.mock(Bundle.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when((BaseBundle)mBundle).putString(AnalyticsController.Params.CID, cid);
}
```

However, it always returns:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putString in android.os.BaseBundle not mocked.
```

I know I can use roboelectric to spin up the simulator and call the real bundle. However, it will slow down the unit test. Does anyone know how to mock the Android .os.base? Thank you.

Comment: can you refactor so that the `new Bundle(1);` can be moved to separate package level method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Add proper set-up

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Bundle.class)
public class MyTest{
```

**2)** Use vanilla Mockito for `do().when()`:

```
Bundle mBundle = PowerMockito.mock(Bundle.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mBundle).putString(AnalyticsController.Params.CID, cid);
```

**3)** Use Powermock for `whenNew()`:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(Bundle.class)
            .withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mBundle);
```

Comment: Hi @Maciej Kowalski Thank you for helping. I put your code in but still does not work. It returns the same error. I'm really curious why it does not work. Why the error is saying that `android.os.BaseBundle not mocked` which is the parent class ? Why it cannot mocked, is it because the Bundle class is final ? Let me know if you have any more insight. Thank you

Comment: ok, then you need PowerMock.createMock(Bundle.class); instead of Mockito.mock

Comment: sorry what is the different between `PowerMockito.mock` and `PowerMock.createMock` ?

Comment: yes actually it should be PowerMockito.mock.. tell me do you still tr yto cast (BaseBundle)?

Comment: Hi @MaciejKowalski I did try this : `Bundle mBundle = PowerMockito.mock(Bundle.class); PowerMockito.whenNew(Bundle.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mBundle);` but no use. It's showing the same result. My friend who is Android developer said it is impossible to do ? What do you think ?

Answer (score 9):

Try to add this in your **build.gradle**

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this means no power mock - yay! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get the answer from my friend. The reason is somehow for mocking android class using powermockito the main class need to be set as prepared for test too :

```
@PrepareForTest({MainClass.class, Bundle.class})
```

Thank you for the effort @Maciej Kowalski. I'll vote up for your effort since it's on the right direction anyway.

**I'm not copy pasting the answer from above, preparing the test for MainClass is the important part.**

Comment: no it's similar but different, look at MainClass.class part that's the important part. Without that it would not work while the answer above just ask me to prepare the test for Bundle.class not MainClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

with mockk you could use constructor-mocks (see mockk.io).

example:

```
mockkConstructor(Bundle::class)
every { anyConstructed<Bundle>().putString(any(), any()) } just runs
```