# Why is my JUnit Test running from Android Studio but fails from CLI?

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

I have a test which uses Bundle.

```
@Test
public void dummy()
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("abcd", "wxyz");
    assertThat(bundle.getString("abcd"), is("wxyz"));
}
```

Now I know, Bundle is stubbed out so I expect my test to fail, which it does when I run it from CLI with error .

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putString in android.os.BaseBundle not mocked

But when I run it from Android Studio the test runs perfectly. I am not using any reflection API, atleast that I know of.

Here is my gradle file

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

I'm trying to understand why it works on Android Studio.

Comment: How are you running this from the command line?

Comment: I am using ```./gradlew test``` Anyways, I'm more intrested to know why this works on Android Studio as I've not stubbed/mocked Bundle

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830130/mock-android-os-basebundle-without-roboelectric

Comment: Thanks for the link. But my question is actually different. I am curious as to why my test is working from Android Studio. I know how to Mock Bundle. It's just that my test is working fine even without mocking Bundle.